# Chapter heading using report class

Tags: sectioning, memoir, chapters

How do I "translate" the following from memoir class to report class? 
I'm currently writing a dissertation in report class and it would be great if I could use this chapter heading:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{tikz, blindtext}
\makechapterstyle{box}{
  \renewcommand*{\printchaptername}{}
  \renewcommand*{\chapnumfont}{\normalfont\sffamily\huge\bfseries}
  \renewcommand*{\printchapternum}{
    \flushright
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw[fill,color=black] (0,0) rectangle (2cm,2cm);
      \draw[color=white] (1cm,1cm) node { \chapnumfont\thechapter };
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }
  \renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\normalfont\sffamily\Huge\bfseries}
  \renewcommand*{\printchaptertitle}[1]{\flushright\chaptitlefont##1}
}
\chapterstyle{box}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

[image: It looks like this]

Comment: Why not just use `memoir`?  If you need to use `report` you can use the `titlesec` package to achieve the same result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following is a fairly adequate adaptation of [`memoir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir)'s `box` chapter style (left is `memoir`; right is `report`):

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz, lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{pgf,lipsum}
\newcommand*{\chapnumfont}{\normalfont\sffamily\huge\bfseries}
\newcommand*{\printchapternum}{
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[fill,color=black] (0,0) rectangle (2cm,2cm);
    \draw[color=white] (1cm,1cm) node { \chapnumfont\thechapter };
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
\newcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\normalfont\sffamily\Huge\bfseries}
\newcommand*{\printchaptertitle}[1]{\flushright\chaptitlefont#1}

\makeatletter
% \@makechapterhead prints regular chapter heading.
% Taken directly from report.cls and modified.
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedleft
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \printchapternum
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 20\p@
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \printchaptertitle{#1}\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
% \@makeschapterhead prints starred chapter heading.
% Taken directly from report.cls and modified.
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedleft
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \printchaptertitle{#1}\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

I've included a similar update to `\@makeschapterhead` that is responsible for setting a starred chapter heading. Some tweaking may be necessary, but that's left up to the reader.

Answer (score 2):

The obligatory approach with »[titlesec](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec)« (at left `report`, at right `memoir`).

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\newcommand*{\chapnumfont}{\normalfont\sffamily\huge\bfseries}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\filleft\bfseries\sffamily}
{\filleft%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[fill,color=black] (0,0) rectangle (2cm,2cm);
    \draw[color=white] (1cm,1cm) node {\chapnumfont\thechapter};
  \end{tikzpicture}
}
{20pt}
{\Huge}

\begin{document}
  \blinddocument
\end{document}
```

---

[image][image]